# Redirect 301

Tags: redirect

Добрый день.

Делаю Redirect 301 /page6/ /diagnostika/, а он в URL проставляет /diagnostika/?q=page6/
Как убрать ?q=page6.
И таких редиректов будут сотни.
Спасибо.

UPD. В данном случае оказалось, что на редирект влияет первоначальное правило для Frendly URL MODX

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Если убрать условие RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA], то перестают работать ЧПУ.
Решение: сразу после RewriteBase /, но до ЧПУ надо прописать условие:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^page6/$ /diagnostika/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

А в самом скрипте нельзя? Как-то так

```
if( $_REQUEST['q'] === 'page6/') 
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');           
    header( "Location: http://site.net/diagnostika/");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Учитывая, что редиректов может быть пару сотен - первый вариант короче.